# Angular Routing Issue (Default View)

Tags: angularjs

I am having an angular application, I want when first navigating to the homepage of my application, to get a specific view called: Search.html, I want anytime I open this home page to render this view, how do we do this in Angular? I have checked the online documentation and it's doing so by having Urls that redirect to another page, for my case, I don't have Urls, I have a landing page where I want to get a specific view when it's opened.

Here's a [link](http://goo.gl/wNyuOZ) to plunker that shows my issue.

Comment: So you don't have any other pages, just a single view?

Comment: I will have other pages as well later on, I want to learn how to load one page at this moment, then I'll have about 5 pages later on.

Comment: It is not clear what issue you're having.

Comment: @BrittanyRutherford I've made a `plunkr` for your reference. http://plnkr.co/edit/n9hG774M1T3DpS6M8J6h?p=preview. If you have have any question just ask.

Comment: @Ursus you always comment on my questions by saying: it's not clear.. when was one of my questions clear to you?

Comment: @AlbertoI.N.J. thanks for your response :). this method you did works in Plunker, but in my case my home page is: main.html, so it's not "/", what do I write in: $routeProvider.when('/main.html', { , do I write: $routeProvider.when('main.html' or "/" .. I am confused in this point.

Comment: @BrittanyRutherford didn't mean to be negative, but you have posted pretty much the same question as 3 hours ago, which also wasn't very clear. As I said before and as your last comment to Alberto seems to confirm, your question is really about relative urls.

Comment: @BrittanyRutherford Do you really need to show `main.html` in your url? One of the main reason why we use `ngRoute` is to get rid of the file extension like `.html` and to make the url cleaner.

Comment: @Ursus as I have stated in my previous question, am still beginner to all of this, so instead of acting like this and give me tooltips about relative Urls, you could just have the time explaining it to me instead of commenting on my question if it's clear or not ..

Comment: @AlbertoI.N.J. No i don't need to use it, I see it everywhere people using clean urls, but it's not happening in my case, how do I do it?

Comment: @BrittanyRutherford Just assign/add `/` to your URL path. E.g. Your home/landing page `/` or if you want to be specific (e.g.) since your `html` file name is `search.html` you can assign it to `/search`.

Comment: @AlbertoI.N.J. but when I first open the site, it shows "http://localhost:53265/Main.html#/"  is that a clean url??

Comment: @BrittanyRutherford What server are you using?

Comment: @BrittanyRutherford I guess you are using apache server. If I'm correct, it's causes by php or apache so I guess you need to have some kind of URL rewriting in your apache server.

Comment: I am using visual studio with windows server 2012

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine the issue is because you need to link the dependency script `angular-route.js` in your head, and also define your app with `ng-app`. Also, putting your controller and module code in separate anonymous functions prohibits the controller from seeing the module variable.

Check out this [fork](http://plnkr.co/edit/NiUCxgwOzMRVU1YlKQgp?p=preview) of your plunkr for how to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use $routeProvider like this

```
angular
.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/search'});
}]);
```

Comment: Try to visit the link of her [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/RmoTxri8ACkq9dzGfC6o?p=preview). To see her existing code.